# How to sand round edges

Tags: sanding, round, roundover

I want to make many irregular shaped cutting boards. for making smooth edges , I want to use round over bit. because of the round edges , I don't know how to sand perfectly. I just found `pipe belt sander` tool. are there any better way/jig for this problem ?

Comment: If you do the routing well and your router bit is properly sharp you should need to do minimal sanding, possibly no sanding at all. If you do need to sand a little light sanding by hand, with paper wrapped around a soft sanding block or a sanding sponge, or just by using paper backed with the fingers should be all that's necessary. If you need to do more sanding than that you should look at the routing step and address any problems there, not do more sanding.

Comment: @Graphus , Thank you for your quick reply , I edited the post and changed `some` to `many` , the raw material is plywood (19mm) the problem is the 1 or 2 mm in middle ( between the round overs) the hard part is the count of the boards , looking for the fast solution , But I think I should do that by hand finally

Comment: If you need to sand the unrouted portion of the edge then careful sanding with a standard sanding block can be perfectly sufficient, but if you want to ensure they remain flat and square to the faces you might want to make a simple sanding jig, see [this Answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5291/cutting-dressed-pine-to-make-it-narrower/5293#5293). But getting the edges of plywood to a very nice finish can also be done with a hand plane (generally working in towards the centre from both ends to prevent chipout at the corners).

Answer (score 1):

A well-executed roundover should require very little sanding. I might start at 240 grit. You can back your sandpaper with a sponge or wad of cloth so that it will conform to the edge even better than your hand will. A sharp bit and a light touch are key.

I will note, though, that rounding over plywood edges can be problematic. The layered surface of plywood doesn't always make a smooth surface for the bearing to glide over, and the alternating grain of the layers can leave you with some tearout, even creating voids at times.

Also I would think twice about using plywood for cutting boards if you mean them for food preparation. Plywood's veneer layer may be good quality wood but the layers are joined with adhesives which are not necessarily food safe. By rounding over the edges you are almost certainly exposing more of these adhesives to contact with food. With a countertop or table, you can protect with a polyeurethane finish and come away with a food safe surface, but this won't work well on a cutting board that's going to see a lot of direct knife contact.